# Captura utilizando Xpath

Tags: python, scrapy, xpath

Estou fazendo uma captura de um site utilizando python (scrapy) e xpath

Como capturar apenas o 232.990 do código abaixo?

```
<div class="price-advantages-container">
    <div class="price-comparison">
        <div itemprop="price" class="price">
               <div>
                    <span>R$</span> 232.990
               </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Tentei com  response.xpath('//div[contains(@class, "price")]/div/text()') e o mesmo retornou caracteres invisíveis como:

```
[<Selector xpath='//div[contains(@class, "price")]/div/text()' data='\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\t'>,
 <Selector xpath='//div[contains(@class, "price")]/div/text()' data='\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t'>,
 <Selector xpath='//div[contains(@class, "price")]/div/text()' data='\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t'>,
 <Selector xpath='//div[contains(@class, "price")]/div/text()' data=' 232.990\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t'>,
 <Selector xpath='//div[contains(@class, "price")]/div/text()' data='\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\t'>,
 <Selector xpath='//div[contains(@class, "price")]/div/text()' data='\r\n\t\t\t\t\t'>]
```

Comment: Os caracteres invisíveis sempre vão vir. Basta fazer um `.trim()` na string pra removê-los.

Answer (score 3):

Você pode filtrar pelo atributo `itemprop` do elemento, ao invés de filtrar todas as divs que possuam `price`no nome da classe. Estou usando o `extract_first()` para retornar apenas o primeiro match e depois `strip()`para remover os espaços em branco do texto.

```
from scrapy import Selector

source = '''<div class="price-advantages-container">
    <div class="price-comparison">
        <div itemprop="price" class="price">
               <div>
                    <span>R$</span> 232.990
               </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>'''

selector = Selector(text=source)

price = selector.xpath('//div[@itemprop="price"]/div/span/following-sibling::node()').extract_first().strip()

print("[*] Price: {}".format(price))
```

Resultado:
**[*] Price: 232.990**